# Chat bot feature requests

Tags: discussion, chat, chatbot

## Notice: *project was disbanded*

I am the [half-robot side of syb0rg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/27623/syb0rg) that will be posting the recent answers of Code Review to the [CR Answers chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12723/cr-answers).  This is simply a place where you can post your feature requests.

Implementation time will depend on many variables, such as the complexity of the request, if your request includes example code for me to implement or not, the number of upvotes behind a feature request, and my amount of free time that I have.

Please post your request in this format:

> #### Title of feature request
>
> - Specific details on how the feature will work.
> - Example of usage (if applicable)
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Example code (if applicable)
> ```

Comment: [Context](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44511/9357)

Answer (score 11):

#### Include tags with question

The auto-inline feature of answers on Chat does not include the tags of the question that was asked. Can the tags be included before/after the answer?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

## Register for Pings

- Allow users to send a chat message in order to register with the bot so that the bot will alert the user when certain posts are made.

---

## Example usage:

- `!follow tag:Objective-C` -- This would register myself with the bot as following everything posted to the Objective-C tag and the bot should ping me any time a question or answer is posted to this tag.
- `!follow mine` -- This would be similar to above, except this command would automatically register me with the bot for every tag I have marked as a favorite.
- `!unfollow tag:Objective-C` -- Self-explanatory.  This command should remove me as a follower for the given tag.
- `!unfollow all` -- Again, self-explanatory.  This command will completely unregister me from all pings from the bot.

Comment: I am unsure about the `!follow mine` feature, since I think I can only access my own favorite tags, not other peoples.  But I would have to look deeper into this.

Comment: Ah, seems you're right.  I was looking at your profile to see if I could see your tags, but it doesn't look like it.  Best I can do is see the tags you have the highest score in... but this is almost certainly going to include tags one wouldn't want to follow.

Comment: I like how this feature could mean coming back to CR with "47 unread notifications" after a weekend off ;)

Comment: Just depends on what you decide to follow.  I'd have to take a few months off while registered to Objective-C & iOS before i racked up anywhere near that number.

Answer (score 10):

#### Chat bot kill switch

Give room owners the ability to stop the bot by typing some key phrase.  It should then either exit, or at the very least, be quite for a long time.  This will allow room owners to limit the damage if a bug causes the bot to go crazy and the bot's owner is not available to take care of things.

For a phrase, pick something easy to remember, and don't require it to match too exactly.  The kill switch shouldn't be too easy to hit, but it shouldn't be too hard, either.  Perhaps something such as `/\bstop +bot\b|\bbot +stop\b/`

Comment: How about `@bot: die`

Comment: I figure it should be `gtfobot`

Comment: I upvoted this, but since the bot is in its own chatroom I think a kill switch is relatively YAGNI.

Answer (score 9):

#### Post meta answers

Right now the chat bot only posts answers from the main site, and not meta.  It should post answers from both.

Comment: Are you talking to yourself or to your half pa... wait rob0t is real!?! **Alien Invasion** run run run...!

Answer (score 5):

#### Make it open source

- Github it

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: https://github.com/CodeReviewCommunity/Ruby-Chat-Bot

Comment: Now I'm going to have to learn ruby.

Answer (score 5):

#### Auto-star "lol" posts

Give <s>Malachi a break</s> *that bot some personality*, make it automatically star "lol"-only chat posts in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

This way we can keep the meme alive, and spare our stars :)

Comment: also make it call TS when it's out..

Comment: Would there still be a limit to this?  After all, regular chat users have a star limit.

Comment: @Jamal all users are star-capped. No bot is exception :)

Comment: @Jamal Using the SE API would limit the stars to that of a typical user, I'm not sure with using web sockets, but I assume it will be the same.

Comment: can't believe that I haven't seen this answer yet.